# Unwind Segue to a Different UITabBarController Tab?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue, uitabbar

I have an application with a UITabBarController with two tabs, each hooked up to their own NavigationControllers (let's call these NavigationControllers A and B).

I have a logout button in a ViewController connected to NavigationController A that I want to have redirect to the first ViewController connected to NavigationController B. Following what I found online, I created an unwind segue in the ViewController connected to NavigationController B and created a manual segue from the ViewController connected to NavigationController A to its respective "Exit" property which calls the unwind segue I created previously.

I gave this manual segue a name of "logoutSegue", but when I call         `performSegueWithIdentifier("logoutSegue", sender: self)` from the ViewController connected to NavigationController A, nothing happens.

I'm relatively new to iOS development, so I thought I'd ask here to see if anyone could point me as to what I've done wrong.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How about make a `protocol` like `navigationController:willPopViewController:`, and implement it in the `UITabBarController` instance?

Comment: @Raptor: Sorry. Misclicked and posted by accident before I was done.

Comment: @zy.liu Do you mind elaborating on what you mean by this a bit? I'm not sure if I follow how this will solve my problem.